# Is there a python module, which can turn geocoordinates into the name of the corresponding city?

Tags: python, geolocation, reverse-geocoding, street-address, city

I have a bunch of coordinates and I want to transform them to human readable addresses. Is there a way to achieve this? It would be **great if i can get the *name* of the city** where the coordinates are located in.

Comment: Reverse geocoding is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Google Maps [Reverse Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

Comment: If you're doing this, be wary of their usage limitations:

*the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12).*

Answer (score 1):

If you can do with political units instead of street addresses I would suggest Pete Warden's Data Science Toolkit: http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#coordinates2politics

With Google Maps API, you are limited to 2500 requests per day. Warden's toolkit is open source and you can run your own server. The caveat is this: "This API relies on data gathered by volunteers around the world for OpenHeatMap, along with US census information and neighborhood maps from Zillow."